# Avoid creation of JDK classes in Apache CXF wsdl2java task

Tags: cxf, java

I have a WSDL file with defines a java.io.Exception:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:tns="http://io.java" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://io.java">
<xsd:complexType name="IOException">
<xsd:sequence/>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

When generating Java classes using the Apache CXf wsdl2java task, it generates a class like this (which causes compile errors, as it is not a valid java.io.IoException):

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "IOException")
public class IOException {
}
```

Is there a way to prevent CXF from generating JDK classes?

Thx! :)

Answer (score 1):

You definitely need to change your namespace.

```
targetNamespace="http://io.java"
xmlns:tns="http://io.java"
```

If you have such namespace and the complex type named `IOException` of course there will a problem. And why in the world you named the namespace like this `http://io.java`?

Change the namespace for e.g.:

```
targetNamespace="http://yourcompany.com/yourservice"
xmlns:tns="http://yourcompany.com/yourservice"
```

You you'll be good.